# Xamarin iOS app throws JIT compile errors only in Distribution builds

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, jit, aot

For some reason my iOS app suddenly started crashing consistently in my last deployment (built with Xamarin iOS 6.4.5.0 Indie), and it only crashes in the App Store builds. I have tested it thoroughly on different environments on other builds (Debug, Ad-Hoc) and they all worked fine, but once it gets deployed to the App Store, it always crashes when it is loading images with the SDWebImage library:

```
RESAASMobileiOS[3591] <Warning>: Unhandled managed exception: Attempting to JIT compile method 'SDWebImage.WebCacheUIImageViewExtension:SetImage (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImageView,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl,MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage,SDWebImage.SDWebImageOptions,SDWebImage.SDWebImageCompletedHandler)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
     (System.ExecutionEngineException)
      at RESAAS.Mobile.iOS.ReblastTableViewSource.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at RESAAS.Mobile.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've tried investigating what this meant but haven't found a decent solution yet. Note that the SDWebImage::SetImage method has been working for the past couple of months, but it is suddenly failing consistently now.

The SDWebImage library version was 3.2, I've updated it to 3.3.1 and resubmitted my app to the App Store. But in the meanwhile, if anyone can provide any pointers of what the cause of this issue might be, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are there any differences in the project configuration between Ad-Hoc and AppStore builds for your project (the iOS Build options page in the project options is the most relevant part).

Comment: In particular check that `--gsharedvt=false` is **NOT** part of your of the options given to `mtouch` (in your build logs). That option is `true` by default.

Comment: same error here - was a solution ever found?

Comment: Same error, some solution @creatiiv ?

Comment: Hey - from memory, my solution was that the project options tab is bugged for xamarin. It sometimes switches modes back to other ones so you have to fiddle with the settings until it builds.